# Search for an occurence in an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

I don't know if I have the terminology right, but I have created the following function:

```
function myCollection(zip, municipality, info) {  

    this.myZip = zip;  
    this.myMuni = municipality;  
    this.myInfo= info;
}
```

Then I create the following array and add data to it:

```
var myArray = new Array();

myArray[0] = new myCollection("1000", "municipality A", "info A");
myArray[1] = new myCollection("2000", "municipality B", "info B");
myArray[2] = new myCollection("2000", "municipality C", "info C");
myArray[3] = new myCollection("3000", "municipality D", "info D");
```

**What I would like to achieve:**

- search inside myArray where a certain zip code in myCollection occurs
- display the rest of the data from myCollection for that zipcode
- do the same for all other occurences of that same zipcode within the collection

A search for zip "2000" in the examply above should output:

2000, municipality B, info B
2000, municipality C, info C

**My train of thoughts**

I thought I'd find the occurences (indexes) where the string occurs and then retrieve the required data like this:

```
console.log(myArray[i].myInfo);
```

where i is the index within the array where

```
myArray[i].myZip
```

matches "2000".

However, I can't get the indexOf to work to search for a string within the object I created, nor can I retrieve all the other occurences that match the same criteria.

Did I choose the right way to do this to start with?

How should I approach this, if you know jQuery or other external libraries should be avoided?

I hope I'm a bit clear - thank you for your thoughts and advice.

Comment: Just loop over your array and test `myArray[i].myZip===mySearchedValue`. Then i is the index you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a good old `while` loop :

```
function findAll(array, fn) {
    var result = [], i = -1;
    while (++i < array.length) {
        if (fn(array[i]) === true) result.push(array[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage example :

```
var a = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }];
var result = findAll(a, function (item) {
    return item.a !== 2;
});
result; // [{ a: 1 }, { a: 3 }]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate over object:

```
search = function (arr, keyName, value) {
    if (arr && keyName && value) {
        var i, j = arr.length;
        for (i = 0; i < j; i += 1) {
            if (arr[i][keyName] === value) {
                return {
                    index : i, 
                    item : arr[i]
                }
            }
    };
    return {}
};
```

And then:

```
search(myArray, 'myZip', 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `indexOf` is current `i` value, so you can simply do `var c = myArray[i];` to get collection, that satisfies your filter criteria. If you want to return more result than first collection found, simply add them sequentially to a new array and return it at the end.